# Is 'What does a domain register do' really off-topic for us?

Tags: discussion

I was a touch surprised to see this question '[what does a domain registrar do](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26890/what-does-a-domain-register-do-e-g-namecheap)' was closed as off topic, its a little confused but it's basically asking how DNS works and what a registrars role in that process is.

On its face that would appear to be exactly our wheelhouse, if it isn't whose is it?

Answer (score 2):

"How the Internet works" does not fall under "the operation of websites which you control" as stated in the [faq](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq). If the question related to a DNS problem or domain problem they were having it would be a different story.

Comment: Fair point. But as I commented below isn't it a decent opportunity for a canonical answer about how DNS works, we do get a lot of problem questions where the OP cannot identify where/with whom the settings problem might be.

Comment: In those cases they need to make sure their question indicates they are having a problem and demonstrate that the question will help them solve that problem. Otherwise asking just because they want to know is off-topic here. Don't forget, there's always chat for these kind of questions.

Comment: Again, fair point. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: The question just had a misleading title. An answer saying they allow you to register your domain name suits the title. But the body of the question is DNS related. The question is somewhat answered here http://security.stackexchange.com/a/802 it may have been better suited on Server Fault

Answer (score 1):

Seems closer to "not a real question" on the basis that it is apparent that the asker knew the right terminology and claimed some knowledge of the domain name system - but did not consult Google/Wikipedia about the fundamentals.

Comment: I'd agree that would be a better closure reason, but it seems a good opportunity for a canonical answer on the subject.